# get model attribute dynamically in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, models

How can I get the attribute from the model object dynamically? I have the attribute of the User object as string:

```
u = User.find(1)
```

Can I do something like  `u.get("user_id")`

Comment: I'm not totally understanding this question. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Feel free to accept an answer from some given below if you're happy? Not close to what you need?

Comment: If you're talking about only ActiveRecord objects (as in the code example), you should probably be more explicit about it in the title and question. (I didn't realize this until I tried the answer.) The chosen answer treating the model as a hash only works for ActiveRecord objects and only for attributes that are columns.

Comment: I presume from context here that you mean to actually pull the attribute from the data store, otherwise it would be obvious to use `u.user_id` or one of several other simpler forms.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could try using the ActiveRecord model instance like a hash.

```
u = User.find(1)
name = u[:name]
field = "first_name"
first_name = u[field]
```

Comment: +1 This is the conventional approach when the attribute name isn't known in advance.

Comment: Note that this only works for attributes that are columns. It does not work for attributes made accessible through attr_accessor.

Comment: Yes, assuming "dynamically" means getting a fresh value of the attribute straight from the data store, then you must start by getting a fresh copy of the object from the data store, e.g. `<active_record_class>.find(id)` and then use the attribute value from the fresh copy as described here by @aditya-sanghi.  The read_attribute method does not hit the database.

Answer (score 13):

Yet another approach:

```
attr = :first_name
@user.read_attribute attr
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
user = User.find(1)
```

then something like this should do what you require

```
user.send('field_name')
```

Comment: When working with enum attributes, this is the only way I've found that returns the field as a string rather than its raw integer value.

Comment: `user.public_send('field_name')` also works and is more secure

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
u = User.find(1)
attr = "first_name"
u.send(attr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I totally understand your questions. Try something like:

```
User.find(1).name
```

if you mean you only want to fetch from DB specific attribute you can do:

```
User.find(1,:select => :name)
```