# Dynamically determining Rails model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, attributes, rails-activerecord

I have a model (simplified version below - the full one has a **lot** more fields) on which I want to do a search.

```
class Media < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :subject, :title, :ref_code

  validates :title, :presence => true
  validates :subject, :presence => true

  def self.search(terms_hash)
    return if terms_hash.blank?

    composed_scope = self.scoped

    terms_hash.each_pair do |key, value|
    if self.respond_to? key and not value.is_blank?
      value.split(' ').each do |term|
        term = "%#{term}%"
        composed_scope = composed_scope.where("#{key} LIKE ?", term)
      end
    end
    composed_scope
  end
end
```

Since the advanced search form is almost identical to the form used to create/update instances of the model, I want to create a method that dynamically looks through the params list of the request and matches form fields to model attributes via the name. So if the search request was,

```
/search?utf8=✓&ref_code=111&title=test&subject=code&commit=Search
```

then my controller could just call Media.search(params) and it would return a scope that would search the appropriate fields for the appropriate value(s). As you can see I tried using `respond_to?` but that is only defined for **instances of the model** rather than the actual model class and I need something that ignores any params not related to the model (eg. utf8 and commit in this case). If this all works well, I plan to refactor the code so that I can reuse the same method for multiple models.

Is there a class method similar to `respond_to?`? How would you go about the same task?

I know this is related to [get model attribute dynamically in rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996455/get-model-attribute-dynamically-in-rails-3) but it doesn't really answer what I'm trying to do because I want to do it on the the **model** rather than an **instance of the model**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [`columns` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-columns) on ActiveRecord model classes so you can easily get a list of attribute names:

```
names = Model.columns.map(&:name)
```

You could remove a few common ones easily enough:

```
names = Model.columns.map(&:name) - %w[id created_at updated_at]
```

The `accessible_attributes` class method might also be of interest, that will tell you what has been given to `attr_accessible`.

Comment: Thanks. The columns method is perfect for my needs!

I always find it so hard to find what I need in the API because of the way everything is spread across so many classes and modules.

Comment: Quick update:

I also stumbled across `columns_hash` which uses the column names as the keys and the same info as `columns` for the values.